# Reliably retrieve PHP constant from a file

Tags: php, regex, constants

**Latest Edit:

Well, I came up with fairly "reliable" :) solution in form of a (portable) function, but since some ppl here got irked enough by not understanding the problem and blocked this question (a military solution: kill what you do not understand), I cannot post it here. Pity.**

I have a set of files, which contain constants, like below.

```
define ('LNG_GSU_LNK_LBL',  '[details]');
define( 'LNG_METHODCROSS_GSU_CLS'   ,'class');
define('GSU_METH'  ,  'method');
define ( 'CROSS_GSU_ACTION_NO_REMOVE', 'cannot remove \' module \'(is); deployed');
```

What would be most reliable method to retrieve constant names and values from given, selected file.

EDIT:

I need to get these constants into array, without defining them actually, directly by reading file, e.g.:

```
array('LNG_GSU_LNK_LBL'=>'[details]','LNG_METHODCROSS_GSU_CLS'=> 'class')
```

... etc

EDIT 2:
So far I got this far:

```
$file_array = file($path, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

//implode lang file into a string removing php tags
$string1 = implode('', $file_array);
$string2 = str_replace(array(''), '', $string1);

//regex removing content between markers
$regex = '/\/\*.+?\*\//si';
$replace_with = '';
$replace_where = $string2;
$string3 = preg_replace($regex, $replace_with, $replace_where);

//regex: remove multiple newlines
$string4 = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $string3);
```

EDIT 3:

expected result

```
array (
'LNG_GSU_LNK_LBL' => '[details]',
'LNG_METHODCROSS_GSU_CLS' => 'class',
'GSU_METH' => 'method',
'CROSS_GSU_ACTION_NO_REMOVE' => 'cannot remove \' module \'(is); deployed'
);
```

Comment: just include\require it.

Comment: Uh.......what? Reliable?

Comment: no one ever asks for an un-relaibel way to do something

Comment: As you tagged regex, are you asking how to retrieve the names and values without actually running the  code and defining the  constants?

Comment: I do not know constant names, so including requiring will not help. Preferably, I would like to get them into an array with key:name, val:value. Also since structure is irregular, there is a problem wit regex - hence "reliable".

Comment: if you don't know the constants name, there's something wrong with your approach - what's the big picture here?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard word "reliable" had to do with regex, since structure is irregular, I'm having difficulty formulating "reliable" regex;

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of stuff that you haven't told us! I'll bet you didn't expect the Spanish Inquisition! Let's go out and come in again...

Comment: @Steve: yes, preferably into an array;

Comment: If you don't know the names and they are not included/required how are you planning to get to them?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard by reading file directly  I just have problem with "reliable" regex

Comment: I think he doesn't want to use the constants, but rather only get  their names and their values, as they come "in a set of files". Something like `preg_match_all("#define\('([-_\w]+)','(.+)');#Ui", $texttoreplace, $matches); // then play with $matches`

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DanMan I'm trying to put constants from selected file (only!) into an array (preferably)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to include the file, then you should use: [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.token-get-all.php).

Otherwise, you should require/include the file containing them and you can iteratively use `get_defined_constants()`:

```
$all = array();

$consts = get_defined_constants();
foreach($consts as $k=>$v){
   if (strpos($k,"LNG")===0 && !isset($all[$k]))    
      $all[$k]=$v;
}
```

Note that parsing php source code is like parsing [HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), better bet avoid it.

Comment: There are dozens of files with constants. There are thousands of constants in them, each of them starts with "LNG". Plus I need to get constants from given (selected) file only.

Comment: What's the problem to include selected only files? you can do it in a `foreach() {include()}`

Comment: Problem is that at the given time (when selected file is processed/included) other files with LNG constants can be included and constants from these files will be picked up by get_defined_constants(), so it will not work, as I need only constants from selected file.

Comment: To clarify: constants not necessarily start with LNG_ - some do not.

Answer (score 1):

Building on dynamic's answer, include the file within another, separate, web accessible file, that is not loaded within your current application (so will have no other user defined constants at run time):

```
//standalone.php
include "that_file.php";

$consts = get_defined_constants(true);
$newUserConsts = $consts['user'];
echo json_encode($newUserConsts);

//within your application

$newUserConsts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/standalone.php'));
```

Or if you cant make a separate web accessible file:

```
$consts = get_defined_constants(true);
$existingUserConsts = $consts['user'];

include "that_file.php";

$consts = get_defined_constants(true);
$newUserConsts = $consts['user'];

var_dump(array_diff_key($newUserConsts, $existingUserConsts));
```

Comment: I tried this idea (array_diff) but there were problems with streamlining it .. thank you for your time thou